# Class Design - Image Upload - Resize (no cropping)

Tags: php, class

Here is the edited class which inlcudes the answer:

EDIT: Included Answers

```
<?php

class Upload
{
    private $originalWidth, 
            $originalHeight, 
            $newWidth, 
            $newHeight, 
            $maxMedium = 50, 
            $maxSmall = 20;

    private $src = NULL;

    private 
            $fileType,
            $fileName,
            $sessionId,
            $path_medium,
            $path_small;

    function __construct($fileType, $fileName)
    {
        if(1)
        {
            Session::start();
            Session::activate(0, 1000, 'Test Account A', 'bookmarks');
        }

        /**
         *    Initialize the Object
         */

        $this->sessionId = Session::get('id');
        $this->path_medium = PICTURES . "/$this->sessionId.jpg";
        $this->path_small = PICTURES . "/$this->sessionId-1.jpg";
        $this->fileType = $fileType;
        $this->fileName = $fileName;

        /**
         *    Instantiate the Object
         */

        $this->instantiate();
    }

    private function instantiate()
    {
        $this->createImages();
        $this->updateSessionAndDb();
    }

    private function createImages()
    {
        if(move_uploaded_file($this->fileName, $this->path_medium))
        {
            if($this->get_image($this->path_medium))
            {
                list($this->originalWidth,$this->originalHeight)=getimagesize($this->path_medium);
                $this->newWidth = $this->originalWidth;
                $this->newHeight = $this->originalHeight;
                // these could each be another class instead of two functions..but no time to refactor further
                $this->resize_move($this->maxMedium,$this->path_medium);
                $this->resize_move($this->maxSmall,$this->path_small);
                imagedestroy($this->src);
            }
        }
    }
    private function updateSessionAndDb()
    {
        $db = new Database();
        $result = $db->_pdoQuery('none', 'update_picture', array($this->sessionId));
        Session::set('picture',1);
    }
    private function resize_move($max, $path)
    {
        $this->makeProportions($max);
        $image_true_color = imagecreatetruecolor($this->newWidth, $this->newHeight);
        imagecopyresampled($image_true_color, $this->src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $this->newWidth, $this->newHeight, $this->
        originalWidth, $this->originalHeight);
        imagejpeg($image_true_color, $path);
        imagedestroy($image_true_color);
    }
    private function makeProportions($max)
    {
        $this->newWidth=$this->originalWidth; 
        $this->newHeight=$this->originalHeight;
        if(($this->originalWidth > $this->originalHeight) && ($this->originalWidth > $max))
        {
            $this->newWidth = $max;
            $this->newHeight = ($max / $this->originalWidth) * $this->originalHeight;
        }
        elseif($this->originalHeight > $this->originalWidth && $this->originalHeight > $max)
        {
            $this->newHeight = $max;
            $this->newWidth = ($max / $this->originalHeight) * $this->originalWidth;
        } 
        elseif ($this->originalWidth > $max)
        {
            $this->newWidth = $this->newHeight = $max;
        }
    }
    private function get_image($path)
    {
        $type_creators = array( 
            'image/gif' => 'imagecreatefromgif', 
            'image/pjpeg' => 'imagecreatefromjpeg', 
            'image/jpeg' => 'imagecreatefromjpeg', 
            'image/png' => 'imagecreatefrompng'); 
        if(array_key_exists($this->fileType, $type_creators)) 
        { 
            $this->src = $type_creators[$this->fileType]($path); 
            return true; 
        }
    return false; 
    }
}
```

Comment: "public function get_image($path)" not "function get_image($path)". Although, as you can tell, mixing static and non-static functions can be done I try not to do it. As you can see you are passing a variable that is a class attribute and the static function can not access it.

Comment: Your **upload** class is actually **resizer** (or something similar)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things I noted:

- Your method and variable name should be clearer.  Specifically, `rmove` should be renamed to something more descriptive, as well as every single one of your private member variables.  Shoot for clarity rather than brevity with function and variable names.
- Remove references to $_FILES and $_SESSION from you class, and instead pass that information into the constructor.  There is no need to couple this class with the implemenation details of the surrounding client code.  You might want to reuse it in some other circumstance where the email wasn't in the session variable, or the file info was not in $_FILES.
- You can rewrite your `get_image()` method as follows, to make it cleaner and shorter.  Note that using this method, adding support for new image types simply involves adding them to the array at the start of the method.  You could even move that array out of the method and provide it as a static member variable.

  ```
  function get_image($path)
  {
  $type_creators = array(
      'image/gif' => 'imagecreatefromgif',
      'image/jpeg' => 'imagecreatefromjpeg',
      'image/png' => 'imagecreatefrompng',
  );

  $img_type = $_FILES['ufile']['type'];

  if (array_key_exists($img_type, $type_creators)) {
      $this->src = $type_creators[$img_type]($path);
      return true;
  }
  return false;
  }
  ```
- Don't pass member variables as arguments into methods.  Remember, they are automatically available already.  So rather than `$this->rmove($this->max1,$path3);`, simply access `$this->max1` from within `rmove`.
- Consider breaking `rmove` down into smaller private functions whose names clearly describe what is going on in each case of the if statement.
- Also, `rmove` is performing two distinct operations right now: 1) Recalculating the true width and height and 2) creating a new version of the image based on these dimensions.  I would break it down into two methods that perfrom each of these tasks separately.
- Finally, a larger issue to consider: This class does not have any public API.  There is no reason any of its methods need to be public right now, as client code will never use them.  Right now, the class is just acting as container code to do a bunch of tasks that should be triggered after a file upload.  So you should consider rethinking how client code could use this class in other circumstances.

Comment: Please do :) just curious, how do you have a 329 reputation having never registered?

Comment: I guess it keeps tracks of my IP or simply a session var, I don't know for sure.

Comment: oh yes, functional programming is fun.  here's a simple proof of concept: http://codepad.viper-7.com/g8A9dq

Comment: I added in the new class to the question with all of your updates...if you see anything else let me know....thanks again